# Solaris 10, useradd command

Tags: solaris, useradd

When I used `useradd` command to add a new user for my Solaris 10 System, I specify `/home/user-name` to be its home directory.

but the command didn't run successfully, and when I put the `/export/home/user-name` as its home directory it runs successfully.

The first command is: `useradd -md "/home/munix" -s "/bin/ksh" munix` --> give me an error, which is the home directory can not be created, but the user is added to passwd file

the second command is: `useradd -md "/export/home/munix munix" munix` --> home directory created successfully

why????

Comment: do /home/munix and /export/home/munix point to the same location?

Comment: No, they don't point to the same location

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Solaris `/home` is managed by the automounter by default. The simplest way if you don't need that functionality is to disable it.

Just comment out the line that reads something like `/home auto_home -nobrowse` in the `/etc/auto_master` file and then restart autofs:

```
svcadm restart autofs
```